# Cast Errors While Populating Referenced Mongoose Documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema looks like the following:

```
User Schema {
    name: String,
    email: String
}

Job Schema {
    title: String,
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    helper: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
}
```

Both Users and Jobs use ObjectId's as their ID type.

Part of my application requires me to query the job collection for jobs that fit certain criteria. As part of this query I perform a population of the referenced user documents. Somethings like the following:

```
Job
  .find(query, null, options)
  .populate('owner helper', 'name email')
  .sort(sort)
  .exec(err, function(results) {
    ...Do Something with populated documents
  })
```

However, this is throwing an error.

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "b" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'b',
  path: '_id' }
```

I have checked all of the user object's ids and they all seem valid. I don't understand what could be causing this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems like you had some bad reference in your Jobs collection. Check out all the `owner` and `helper` fields

Comment: This was it. One of the owner fields was incorrectly formatted. Thank you so much for your help.